# Java throws InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I started to learn Java and I'm doing some exercises from my book. While doing one, I faced this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`. I'm writing a simple program which takes data from the `.txt` file and returns it to the console. Here's the code:

`Employee.java`:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
        jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
    }
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid){
        out.printf("Pay an employee %s ", name);
        out.printf("(%s) ***$", jobTitle);
        out.printf("%,.2f", amountPaid);
    }
}
```

`DoPayroll.java`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class DoPayroll {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File ("EmployeeInfo.txt"));
        for(int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++){
            payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
        }
    }
    static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner) {
        Employee anEmployee = new Employee();
        anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
        aScanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

`EmployeeInfo.txt`:

```
John
Manager
15000.00
Alice
Secretary
8000.00
Bob
Engineer
12000.00
**an empty line**
```

**error log from compiler:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at DoPayroll.payOneEmployee(DoPayroll.java:19)
    at DoPayroll.main(DoPayroll.java:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that the `Scanner` uses the current `Locale` to parse a `Double` so you need to explicitly set a `Locale` that allows to use a dot as decimal separator such as `Locale.US` for example. So to fix your code, you simply need to add this into your code before the `for` loop:

```
diskScanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: removed it, still have the same issue :(